# Permission denied in pycharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, compiler-errors, discord.py

I'm getting the permission denied error every time I try to access a folder on the computer that's not in the same directory as the python script.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import find
import random
from random import choices


client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="brt ")

@client.command()
async def hi(ctx):
    if ctx.channel.is_nsfw():
        await ctx.message.channel.send(random.choice(file=discord.File(r"D:\New folder")))
        await ctx.message.channel.send('Hi'+ctx.message.author.mention)
    else:
        await ctx.message.channel.send('Channel isnt nsfw... ' + format(ctx.message.author.mention), file=discord.File('gif.gif'))
```

Here's the error message: discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'D:\New folder'

Comment: Are you trying to send the whole folder?

Comment: No, just to send a file from a folder.

Comment: As far as I can see from your code, you are trying to send the folder named `New folder`. I don't think that `random.choices` works for `discord.File` type but I'm not sure. Even if it does work, you should add your `New folder` to desktop or some another file not directly into your D: storage. I think that's why you're getting this error.

Comment: Tried to put it on desktop and even in the same folder where my project is located, but I'm still getting the same error. Also tried to run pycharm as administrator...